# WSO2 IS Federated IdP

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I downloaded WSO2 IS version 5.9.0. I configured an external IDP as suggested here https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/adding-and-configuring-an-identity-provider/ and then I configured the claims and a Service Provider where I want to use SAML2 SSO.

I configured my Service Provider in order to use and advanced configuration for the login process where step one is basic authentication and step 2 is done by using my external IdP.

The same identical configuration works pretty good in my WSO2 5.8.0 while I'm facing a lot of issues in WSO2 IS 5.9.0.

In 5.9.0 version, when I try to log to my application, WSO2 shows to me the login interface but when I click the login by external IdP the popup is empty as showed in this image [image: Federated Authentication]

Moreover I noticed that when I try so modify the application-authentication.xml located in ${WSO2_IS_HOME}/repository/conf/identity my modifications are lost and the file returns to the default state. I tried to insert modification in the deployment.toml but I can't figure how to configure correctly the SAMLSSO.

Then I tried to configure my Service Provider only by showing the external login interface. I get an error. The stack trace is the following:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-14 19:34:50,523] [a7721bfd-6c47-48f2-b31d-d30a0fbb7e06] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.samlsso.manager.DefaultSAML2SSOManager} - SAML Request  :  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://localhost:9443/commonauth" AttributeConsumingServiceIndex="0" Destination="http://localhost:8088/sso" ForceAuthn="true" ID="_84b2f91a208bc6b3ee12383e2cf26652" IssueInstant="2019-10-14T17:34:50.505Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><samlp:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity" NameQualifier="http://wso2_590_ai" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://wso2_590_ai</samlp:Issuer><saml2p:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"/><saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><saml2:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://www.spid.gov.it/SpidL2</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef></saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext></samlp:AuthnRequest>
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-14 19:34:50,524] [a7721bfd-6c47-48f2-b31d-d30a0fbb7e06] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.samlsso.manager.DefaultSAML2SSOManager} - Parameter Map {} tenantDomain carbon.super
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-14 19:34:50,524] [a7721bfd-6c47-48f2-b31d-d30a0fbb7e06] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.samlsso.manager.X509CredentialImpl} - tenantID -1234
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-14 19:34:50,525] [a7721bfd-6c47-48f2-b31d-d30a0fbb7e06] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} - Exception in Authentication Framework java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
    at java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)
    at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder.endTenantFlow(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:1295)
    at org.wso2.carbon.context.PrivilegedCarbonContext.endTenantFlow(PrivilegedCarbonContext.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkUtils.endTenantFlow(FrameworkUtils.java:1505)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.samlsso.manager.X509CredentialImpl.<init>(X509CredentialImpl.java:202)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.samlsso.manager.DefaultSAML2SSOManager.buildRequest(DefaultSAML2SSOManager.java:267)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.samlsso.SAMLSSOAuthenticator.initiateAuthenticationRequest(SAMLSSOAuthenticator.java:123)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.process(AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java:71)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.doAuthentication(DefaultStepHandler.java:502)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handle(DefaultStepHandler.java:267)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java:185)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.GraphBasedSequenceHandler.handle(GraphBasedSequenceHandler.java:111)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:239)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonAuthenticationHandler.doPost(CommonAuthenticationHandler.java:46)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonAuthenticationHandler.doGet(CommonAuthenticationHandler.java:37)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.sendRequestToFramework(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:1592)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.sendToFrameworkForAuthentication(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:827)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleSPInitSSO(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:719)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:270)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doPost(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:156)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.captcha.filter.CaptchaFilter.doFilter(CaptchaFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:74)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:146)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:116)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

By debugging it seems that in the class `org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder` in the method `endTenantFlow()` we try to pop from an empty stack as you can see in this code:

```
public void endTenantFlow() {
    Stack<CarbonContextDataHolder> carbonContextDataHolders = parentContextHolderStack.get();
    if (carbonContextDataHolders != null) {
        currentContextHolder.set(carbonContextDataHolders.pop());
    }
}
```

This code is taken from jar org.wso2.carbon.utils-4.5.1.jar

Do you have any tip? It seems to me a bug but it's a too much evident issue....

Answer (score 2):

I guess I found the bug.

In class `org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.samlsso.manager.X509CredentialImpl` in the constructor there is this piece of code:

```
try {
    /**
     * Get the private key and the cert for the respective tenant domain.
     */
    if (!tenantDomain.equals(MultitenantConstants.SUPER_TENANT_DOMAIN_NAME)) {
        FrameworkUtils.startTenantFlow(tenantDomain);
        //Do some stuffs
    } else {
        //Do other stuffs
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Handle exception
} finally {
    FrameworkUtils.endTenantFlow();
}
```

As you can see the `FrameworkUtils.startTenantFlow(tenantDomain);` is called only if the first if is true. This means that in the finally we have to handle the endTenantFlow() properly. I modified the code in this way:

```
try {
    /**
     * Get the private key and the cert for the respective tenant domain.
     */
    if (!tenantDomain.equals(MultitenantConstants.SUPER_TENANT_DOMAIN_NAME)) {
        FrameworkUtils.startTenantFlow(tenantDomain);
        //Do some stuffs
    } else {
        //Do other stuffs
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Handle exception
} finally {
    if (!tenantDomain.equals(MultitenantConstants.SUPER_TENANT_DOMAIN_NAME)) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("finalizzo il tenant flow per tenant domain " + tenantDomain);
        }
        FrameworkUtils.endTenantFlow();
    } else {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Tenant domain " + tenantDomain + " nessun flow da finalizzare");
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work now

I hope it can be useful

Angelo

Comment: Hey @Angelo, Where can I find its JAVA and how can I export to new JAR?

Comment: Hi @hiren you can find the github repository here https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-samlsso; for wso2 is 5.9.0 you must use tag 5.2.6 (I don't know if wso2 team fixed it in successive tag releases; I gave them the patch). It's maven based project and you need JDK 1.8